# How to define calculated constrained column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I would like adding a default constrain to a column based on another column using `Scalar-valued function`

These is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] 
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL
    [ScrambledId] [int] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT (dbo.MakeItScrambled([Id])) FOR [ScrambledId]

CREATE function [dbo].MakeItScrambled(@Value int)
BEGIN
    --Some logic
    retrun @ScrambledValue
END
```

I need the column `[ScrambledId]` to be Scrambled based on column `[Id]`

It seems that the Column Names are not permitted:

> The name "Id" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are
>   constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added a calculated column you have created a normal column and tried to add a default to it. You cannot reference another column in a default constraint.

**Edit:** This will raise error:

> Computed column 'ScrambledId' cannot be persisted because the column
>   is non-deterministic

<strike>If you want a calculated column then in the table definition use...
`[ScrambledId] AS dbo.MakeItScrambled([Id]) PERSISTED` - I would suggest using persisted where you are calcuting based on a scalar function.</strike>

Alternatively you could add an update/insert trigger to set the value of [ScrambledId] when you insert or update [Id].

Comment: I've tried your first approach and i'm getting an error: computed column  'ScrambledId' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Comment: Hmm, was afraid of that with a scalar function..... 2 options then, either drop the persisted and have it recalculate on read or create an update/insert trigger